# Change background color for google sheets

Tags: java, spring, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm working with google sheet. I want to edit the color of the cells on the sheet. But it doesn't seem to work. Someone please help me.

```
Color color = new Color().setRed(Float.valueOf("1"))
            .setGreen(Float.valueOf("0"))
            .setBlue(Float.valueOf("0"));
    CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat().setBackgroundColor(color);
    CellData cellData = new CellData().setEffectiveFormat(cellFormat);
    List<CellData> cellDataList = List.of(cellData);
    RowData rowData = new RowData().setValues(cellDataList);
    List<RowData> rowDataList = List.of(rowData);

    GridRange gridRange = new GridRange().setSheetId(0).setStartRowIndex(0).setEndRowIndex(1).setStartColumnIndex(1).setEndColumnIndex(2);

    UpdateCellsRequest updateCellsRequest = new UpdateCellsRequest().setRange(gridRange).setRows(rowDataList).setFields("userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor");

    Request request = new Request().setUpdateCells(updateCellsRequest);
    List<Request> requestList = List.of(request);

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest update =
            new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requestList);
    service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate("1uZZkQ8XAgCe1R_tYqoFQ4Kva-H3il-G2mq2cEiAcBqM", update).execute();
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete code? Please see[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by replacing this code

```
CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat().setBackgroundColor(color);
    CellData cellData = new CellData().setUserEnteredFormat(cellFormat);
    RepeatCellRequest repeatCellRequestRed = new RepeatCellRequest()
        .setRange(gridRange)
        .setCell(cellData)
        .setFields("userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor");
    Request request = new Request().setRepeatCell(repeatCellRequestRed);
```